# How to add Microsoft WCF Web Service to Blazor Server Project

Tags: c#, wcf, blazor-server-side

Warning: I am an intern!

I have been tasked with integrating a Microsoft WCF Web service that we have used with our .net application with a new blazor server application we are working on. When adding the connected service, everything works fine, except for some of the System.ServiceModel namespaces. The following code lines are examples of what is giving me issues:

[System.ServiceModel.*OperationContractAttribute*(Action="Example", ReplyAction="Example")]
[System.ServiceModel.*XmlSerializerFormatAttribute*(SupportFaults=true)]
[System.ServiceModel.*ServiceContractAttribute*(ConfigurationName="Example")]
[System.ServiceModel.*MessageContractAttribute*(WrapperName="Example", WrapperNamespace="Example", IsWrapped=true)]

The italicized portions of each line are what is giving me an error in my blazor server app.

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to add a WCF Web service to a blazor server app. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*I have been tasked with integrating a Microsoft WCF Web service that we have used with our .net application with a new blazor server application we are working on*"... Well, personally recommend against it. WCF is dead, I would make the case to move WCF to a more modern and maintainable framework, and definitely not try to mix it with blazor. Anyway ill happily delete this comment once you get the gist.